# remove vs pull vs unset in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I can remove a document or an element by remove, pull, unset.

What are the differences among those three?

Which one is safer way to remove in contemporary commanding issue?

and which one is fastest and efficient way to remove?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`remove` removes a document from the collection. This is like an SQL DELETE.

`$pull` and `$unset` are update operations that change part of the document. They are similar to SQL UPDATE.

`$pull` removes an element from an array.

`$unset` removes the whole array (or any other field).

> and which one is fastest and efficient way to remove?

Since they do completely different things, that is not a meaningful question.

Comment: Somehow I cannot even delete a document through remove({condition}), so I'm trying to remove it by using $pull

Comment: If you can `find` the document with the condition, then you can `remove` it. Are you sure the condition is correct?